# Найти математическое ожидание

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю как находить из плотности, а тут что-то не понятно. Как тут найти ?

Comment: Это вопрос по математике, а не по программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вектор `(ξ, η)` имеет [дискретное распределение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), поэтому через плотность посчитать не получится ([плотность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) есть только у случайных величин, имеющих [абсолютно непрерывное распределение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9#.D0.90.D0.B1.D1.81.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.82.D0.BD.D0.BE_.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.8B.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F)).

В дискретном случае [математическое ожидание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) считается тоже просто, а именно, если [случайная величина](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) `ξ` принимает значения `a_1, ..., a_n` с вероятностями `p_1, ..., p_n`, то её математическое ожидание равно сумме величин `a_i * p_i`.

Например, посчитаем `Eη`. `η` принимает значение `-1/2` с вероятностью `1/12 + 0 + 1/12 = 1/6`, и значение `1/2` с вероятностью `1/4 + 1/2 + 1/12 = 5/6`. Таким образом, `Eη = (-1/2) * (1/6) + (1/2) * (5/6) = 1/3`.